# Loop Cut Proportions Problem / Not Even

Tags: modeling, edges, scale

So I am trying to make loop cuts for the side of a building I am trying to model in order to make inset faces for the windows.

[image: loop cuts not even]

Unfortunately

1. The first double loop cut, scaled down on the x axis (by 0.2) comes
   out to an odd number like 0.4133, as opposed to a nicer 0.4.
2. The second double loop cut, scaled down on the x axis (by 0.2) comes out way thinner than the last loop cut, at 0.1929.

I'm tired of trying to add loop cuts one by one, and manually selecting each edge of the loop cut and moving them back and forth to try and properly align them.

Surely there is a better way I am missing. Like, is there a way to scale loop cuts independent of the length of the wall?

I am a bit of a beginner; I don't understand the best way to do everything, but I do have moderate experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well scaling is always proportional to edge length, after adding one loop cut the resulting edge length will be shorter, hence the same 0.2 factor will naturally yield a smaller absolute value. Add just one loop cut then try using the *Bevel* operator instead, since it uses absolute values for distances, rather than edge length factors.

Comment: @duarte I will give that a go and see how that works for me, so far it appears like it may work as it doesn't add extra uneeded faces from what I've seen. Thank you.